# SQL query with where and distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql query which gets back unique days from a column of time stamp values for a particular user. What I am trying to get back is the count of timestamp values for each unique day for a particular user.

```
 select distinct DAY(time) from users_has_activities
 where usersID = 47;
```

Comment: Do you really mean `DAY(time)` (day of month), or rather `DATE(time)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a count `COUNT(column_name)` with a GROUP BY should do the trick:

```
SELECT DAY(time), COUNT(DAY(time))
FROM users_has_activities
WHERE usersID = 47
GROUP BY DAY(time);
```

Comment: How?  MySQL doesn't have a `COUNTD()` function.

Comment: I changed it to count

Comment: This is the version that is working for me your previous answer               select COUNT(DAY(time))
from users_has_activities
where usersID = 47 
GROUP BY DAY(time);

Comment: If you `GROUP BY DAY(time)` - `COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(time))` will allways return `1`. So you have to use `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT time)` or something else - depending on what you really want to count. But it doesn't make sence like it is now.

Comment: @Paul Yup, you're exactly right, since it's actually the same key as the group by, distinct isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct DAY(time) )
from users_has_activities
where usersID = 47;
```

Comment: I tried this but it return the number of distinct days, not the number of values on each distinct day.

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby clause to get count so it would loook something like followin:

```sql
select DAY(time), count(1)
from users_has_activities
group by DAY(time);
```